# Having difficulties getting slideshow working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been working on a page that needs a custom slideshow but now I'm having issues with getting things to display as needed.

Here are the [Images.](http://bit.ly/10C4FZw)

Slideshow JS, HTML, CSS --> are located [here.](https://github.com/ISynthesiaI/Stack-Overflow)

I figured if I could put a **div** around the **a.slidesjs-previous** and **a.slidesjs-next** I can then add the background: #fff to the div.

But replacing the numbers with bullets is the hardest part so far. What approach should I try?

I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Can we see the HTML markup for the bullets? It would seem they would all just be something like spans, we could count each span and replace it with it's corresponding index value represented as a number.

Comment: Full HTML markup can be found [here](http://bit.ly/Y8YUCl).

Comment: Dude, I was really hoping you'd provide a working example, or at least  `only` the markup for the bullets in question. Really asking us to do way too much leg work here...

Comment: Working example is [here](http://mm.metsalu.com/avaleht.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through the semi-discernable code you'd provided in that github, it would seem as if the JS produces the bullets in a list-item style.

The format seems to be as such;

```
<li class="slidesjs-pagination-item">
    <a href="#" data-slidesjs-item="0"></a>
</li>
```

In the above. the data-slidesjs-item holds reference to which slide it's linked too. For this purpose, the slides are `0 index` based, meaning if we wanted to start at 1, we'd have to add 1.

Looking at the provided CSS, I don't see any special images being used to generate the bullets, nor are there any text-indents, so simply doing:

```
$('.slidesjs-pagination-item a').each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).data('slidesjs-item') +1);
});
```

[And here is a fiddle illustrating the mechanics behind this](http://jsfiddle.net/dBdAv/)

Comment: So if I would want to add a **span** element (which I could customize) to **.slidesjs-pagination-item a** and lose the numbers I need to do what?

Comment: You should need to do nothing. the code I provided should handle it by its self.